# Need a RegEx pattern for comma-separated list of big-endian dates

Tags: regex, vba, excel

Examples:

> 2011-01-01
>
> 2011-01-01,2011-01-28,2011-12-31

etc.

I don't need it to verify that the dates themselves are valid, just that the list is in the correct format.

I'm using:

> ^[0-9]+(,[0-9]+)*$

To match a comma-separated list of numbers, and:

> ^[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}$

matches a single date in the format I want, but:

> ^[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}+(,[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}+)*$

Doesn't seem to work, and I'm not sure why.

Just in case the problem is actually with my Excel VBA function, I'll put that here too:

```
Public Function ValidDateList(ByVal value As String) As Boolean
    Dim oRegEx As Object
    Set oRegEx = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
    With oRegEx
        .Pattern = "^[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}+(,[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}+)*$"
        ValidDateList = .test(value)
    End With
    Set oRegEx = Nothing
End Function
```

Comment: i've put your regex and string [here](http://regexr.com?2t6uu) and it works fine. you can simplify your string to ^\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}+(,\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}+)*$. so maybe the problem's with the function, cant help with that though, soz.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first thing I'd do is take those `+` characters out.

They're a hangover from your multi-digit pattern (the first one) and are, at best, superfluous.

At worst, they *may* be requiring a literal `+` due to the fact your previous pattern already has a repeater on it (you would have to test this theory, I don't know the Excel RE engine that well).

Try:

```
^[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}(,[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2})*$
```

instead.

Comment: taking your version as inspiration: `^(?:[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2},?)+$` assuming that the list will always have at least one item and that trailing commas are ok

Comment: Yeah, I wasn't sure just how good the RE engine in Excel was so, in those cases, I tend to opt for the lowest common denominator.

Comment: Thanks the pluses were the problem, as you said. It works fine now, and I have changed it to allow for single- or double-digit month/day entries.

Comment: I wasn't even aware there was a regex engine in Excel until this question! :-D